# Ansible retry get attempt number

Tags: ansible

I am using a task that connects via ssh to a device. Latency is not always constant and sometimes when the prompt is not displayed in time the task fails.

Assuming it is possible to control the timeout value for this task is it possible to dynamically increase this timeout proportionally to the number of the attempt performed?

Something like this

```
- name: task_name
  connection : local
  task_module:
    args...
    timeout : 10 * "{{ attempt_number }}"
  retries: 3
  delay: 2
  register: result
  until: result | success
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think its possible to get the current attempt number while running the task, it's quite unclear why you're trying to achieve such thing.

Can you elaborate a little bit more?

Comment: Thank you for your help. My question comes from what I have observed when a task fails and ansible tries again to run it:

FAILED - RETRYING: get facts from device (2 retries left).Result was: {
    "attempts": 2, 
    - omitted - 
}
Every time an attempt is performed the attempts value is increased. I was wondering whether is possible to leverage this value in a task to influence its arguments. An example would be to modify the timeout value in order to have more changes to connect.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible, [here are docs](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#retrying-a-task-until-a-condition-is-met).

> When you run a task with until and register the result as a variable, the registered variable will include a key called “attempts”, which records the number of the retries for the task.